# Tensorflow tensor function

Tags: tensorflow

For those who know about this, I would like to know how to run Carlini-Wagner's attack script on a non-Keras model.

Suppose I have class containing a tensorflow graph that implements a classification model:

```
class classifier:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape)
        # [insert mdoel here]
        self.logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=..., units=num_labels, activation=None)
```

I would like to be able to run a predict statement within an optimization loop like this:

```
model = classifier()
output = model.predict(newimg)
```

where "newimg" is a tf.variable that I will be optimizing over.

How can I modify my "classifier" class so that this becomes possible, i.e. a predict method that takes in a Tensorflow variable or placeholder and outputs another?

Essentially this would be equivalent to defining a new graph where I replace the original placeholder x by a non-trainable variable, but this seems dirty.

Comment: I would suggest you change your question title to something like: how to use TensorFlow model to perform inference.

Comment: This is not what I am asking. I want the input to "predict" to be a tensorflow variable that I can optimize over, as in line 90 of the script github.com/carlini/nn_robust_attacks/blob/master/l2_attack.py. In their case, the model is defined using Keras as model=Sequential(). In this case one can use model(data), where data can be both a tensor and an array. I would like to have a similar functionality without relying on keras.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your computation graph into a Tensorflow Session, and use Session.run() method to feed the input image. It should be something like this:

```py
    class classifier:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape)
        # [insert mdoel here]
        self.logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=..., units=num_labels, activation=None)
        self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)

    def predict(self, image):
        pred_logits = self.sess.run(self.logits,
                                    feed_dict={self.x: image})
```

To eval, simply call:

```py
model = classifier()
output_logits = model.predict(newimg)
```

Keep in mind that feeding images one by one is not the optimal solution, if you need to perform evaluation on a large scale dataset, you will need to use the Tensorflow Data pipeline to batch images in parallel and speed-up inference time, which is certainly off the topic.

Comment: newimg is a tensorflow variable, not an array.

Comment: @MathewWilson I see, sorry about the confusion. Let me edit my answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: @MathewWilson I think I still need more context in order to understand what you really want to achieve. Will the newimg change during training? If so it might be not achievable since Tensroflow (at least for 1.x) uses static graph.

Comment: I have a trained model and I want to construct adversarial examples for it (small perturbations of the inputs that the model will misclassify). To do it, you start from a true sample and optimize the noise that must be added to it in order to maximize the probability that it belongs to a prescribed target class. The script in the link I provided implements a strong algorithm to find such examples. The same github repository contains the model on which the attack will be performed, which is implemented using Keras' Sequential.

Comment: I would like to be able to run that attack script on a model like the one I described in the question. So I am asking how I should modify my model class accordingly.

Comment: One dirty way of doing this is to add one variable "noise" to the model graph and then pass x+noise to the first layer of the model (instead of x). The attack script will then optimize over the variable "noise". But this doesn't seem right; I should be deriving another class from the model class that adds the functionality that I need, but I can't figure how.

Comment: @MathewWilson Yeah, optimize on the variable noise could be an option. I think in your case, you can simply use function based model instead of a class based one. When building the graph, you just call a function to pass your image variable to your model, and get the return logits variable, and calculate the loss function with returned logits